# What does this regular expression mean /^.*(?=.{4,5})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$/

Tags: php, regex

Can someone elaborate the following regular expression:

```php
if($pass == $re_pass) {
    //password validation
    $pattern_up = "/^.*(?=.{4,56})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$/";

    if(!preg_match($pattern_up, $pass)) {
        $errPass = "Must be at lest 4 character long, 1 upper case, 1 lower case letter and 1 number exist";
    }
}
```

what I want to achieve is to check the entered password is between the number of 4 and 56. I already specified it in the code. However, when I tried, it can accept more than that range.

My question, is how i can specify the upper limit, i dont want to exceed 56 characters long. And if you can elaborate it more, so i can understand it more. this code is not made by me.

Thanks,

I am trying to do sign up page in php

```php
if($pass == $re_pass) {
    //password validation
    $pattern_up = "/^.*(?=.{4,56})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$/";

    if(!preg_match($pattern_up, $pass)) {
        $errPass = "Must be at lest 4 character long, 1 upper case, 1 lower case letter and 1 number exist";
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `.*` from the beginning of the pattern, and add a `$` anchor to end of the first lookahead

Comment: See the explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/EJ1m3B/1

Comment: Using passwords for a website is less than ideal, but it is common practice so everybody seems to accept the disadvantages. I agree that you should put minimum demands on a password, but I don't see the point of overdoing it. Why would I not be allowed to make my password longer than 56 characters? The simplest way of accepting very long password is by simply ignoring everything over the maximum length you accept.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware *Using passwords for a website is less than ideal*. What do you recommend then? Fingerprint or a blood DNA needle coming out from the DVD drive? :-)

Comment: @Andreas You can google that: [Digital Security: 5 Alternatives to Passwords](https://www.bbvaopenmind.com/en/technology/digital-world/digital-security-5-alternatives-to-passwords/) [Passwords Are Scarily Insecure. Here Are a Few Safer Alternatives.](https://www.entrepreneur.com/article/309054). What you're probably are trying to say is that a password is a very easy way, for website makers, to authenticate an user, and that's true. That is not the same as being an ideal solution, but we often accept the trade-off between security and easy-of-use.

Answer (score 0):

Just use anchors: `^.{4,56}$`

`^` - match beginning of a string

`$` - match end of a string

`.{4,56}` - match any character at least 4 and at most 56 times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bGX1gy/1)

You can use it in positive lookahead: `(?=^.{4,56}$)`